# Using 'IN' Clause in TdParameter

Tags: c#, teradata

Am trying to connect to Teradata using C# code. I need to execute a Select statement, using IN clause, and I need to pass the values dynamically.

Ex:

```
TdCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select EmpNum,EmpName from Employee where EmpName IN (?)";
```

I need to use the TdParameter to set the value for the IN Clause. It can be one or more names. This is part of a Web API and I receive the list of names from the API input.

Can someone guide me on how to accomplish this?

I use .Net 4.5 and Teradata dll version 15.11. Pls let me know if you need more details.

Comment: who provides the employee names ? Is it from the result of another query ? is it in an array/map/..?

Comment: It comes from the API call. It is a list. This is part of a Web API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant think of a better solution than this.

```
List<string> employeeNames = APICall();
cmd.CommandText = "Select EmpNum,EmpName from Employee where EmpName 
                   IN (\"" + String.Join("\",\"", employeeNames) + "\")";
```

or

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select EmpNum,EmpName from Employee where EmpName 
                   IN ('" + String.Join("','", employeeNames) + "')";
```

for single quotes

This would preserve the quotes. let me know if this works.

TdParameter has a list of allowed types (TdType - https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/15.11/help/Teradata.Client.Provider~Teradata.Client.Provider.TdType.html) and array is not one of them.

Comment: It did not work. I tried something similar already before posting here. It tries to treat them as a single string and it returns an empty result. Something like Select EmpNum,EmpName from Employee where EmpName IN ("Name1, Name2")

Comment: understandable, considering list of names is specified as a single parameter. so it should be a single string. how about editing the commandText to have the proper array like in the updated answer.

Comment: this was exactly what I tried too. but it did not work since the string from the array, was still having all the values in a single string. So I had  to tweak this a bit and get it working. Thanks @littlecegian.

Comment: Great. Glad i could help :)

Comment: How can we avoid SQL Injection issue here? I need to implement something similar in a web API, with user input. All callers input has to be treated as untrusted.